# Convert querystring to int in PHP

Tags: php, string

Working on my first PHP site (I'm mainly an ASP programmer), and I need to convert a querystring variable into a number I can then use to query a database. What's the best way to convert to a usable int (I tried intval() already but I keep getting `0` as a result) and also validate it (AKA no single quotes, blah blah) in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP allows for far more flexibility with types than ASP, and will convert between different types automatically.

The best way to ensure a number in your SQL is to use `sprintf()`, for example:

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = ".sprintf("%d", $_POST['userid']) ;
```

When inserting strings delivered by GET or POST into your SQL, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` (assuming your SQL is going to MySQL) to escape anything that needs escaping, so:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users where name = ".sprintf("'%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username'])) ;
```

Comment: What will sprintf() do if a string like "hello" is presented in the querystring instead of a number?

Comment: If you're already using sprintf why not go all the way and do `$sql = sprintf("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = %d", $_POST['userid']);`? Cleaner and no concatenation needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to read input parameters for PHP script - I would recommend using

```
$_POST $_GET
```

arrays, as they hold all that info already parsed.

Comment: I'm already using these, I just need to confirm that the input is a number before I add it to my SQL query.